# Apache superset Unable to login using custom security manager

Tags: apache-superset

I am customizing apache superset login using custom security manager, but unable to redirect the welcome page. My code for custom_security_manager.py is;

```py
from flask import redirect, g, flash, request
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import UserDBModelView,AuthDBView
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import expose
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import BaseSecurityManager
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user

class CustomAuthDBView(AuthDBView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self):
        token = request.args.get('token')
        flash(token, 'warning')
        if token == 'SOME_TOKEN_VALUE':
            user = self.appbuilder.sm.find_user(username=request.args.get('username')) 
            flash(user, 'warning')
            login_user(user, remember=False)
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)
        else:
            flash('Unable to auto login', 'warning')
            return super(CustomAuthDBView,self).login()

class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authdbview = CustomAuthDBView
    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(CustomSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
```

I am using below link for login:

```
http://10.92.123.25:8088/login/?username=admin&token=SOME_TOKEN_VALUE
```

Comment: Hi Farrukh - what's the error you are getting in logs? and what's the superset version?

Comment: Apache superset version is 2.00, with docker, where to check apache superset logs?

Comment: Since the URL you mention is not meant for clicking, because of being a code example, please use the formatting to make that more obvious. I did that for you (using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ). Please review.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add next redirect path in your URL.
Example:

```
http://10.92.123.25:8088/login/?username=admin&token=SOME_TOKEN_VALUE&next=/superset/dashboard/11?standalone=true
```

Comment: Since the URL you mention is not meant for clicking, because of being a code solution, please use the formatting to make that more obvious. I did that for you (using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ). Please review.

Comment: You might also want to add some explanation, in order to increase the perceived helpfulness of your post. Compare [answer]. And maybe take the highly recommended [tour].